Remove painted layer in final jpg
I know this is a long shot but I have a jpg screenshot where someone painted over a portion of it with a red brush. I'd like to be able to see what was painted over.  I have affinity photo, not Photoshop.  Are there any tools I could use to try and extract what was beneath the painted spots?

just FTR the paint is SOLID right, not a percentage alpha? (not "see through" .. ?)

No.
JPGs are flat images and once a pixel is changed, and the file saved, any previous pixel data is gone forever.
This really has nothing to do with any software. It's about the nature of the JPG format, or most, end-use, raster formats. The reality is that is just not possible to "uncover" something that has been painted over completely. It doesn't matter what software you use.
(I'm aware television programs and movies will make what you want seem possible. But much like teleporting, in reality it isn't possible.)

That was what I expected but just wanted to make sure.  Thanks.

@geoffswartz, the image metadata may contain a thumbnail, which, if not changed by the latest change, may be used to (partially) restore the damaged image.
